# Загрузить xml при помощи js

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlparser

Нужно сделать так, чтобы можно было при помощи  взять информацию из файла, который я выберу, а не заранее указывать в коде

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.open("GET","firststudent.xml",false);
   xmlhttp.send();
   xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

  document.getElementById("faculti").innerHTML=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("faculti")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  document.getElementById("spec").innerHTML=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("spec")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  document.getElementById("points").innerHTML=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("points")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

  document.getElementById("specTwo").innerHTML=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("spec")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  document.getElementById("subjectsTwo").innerHTML=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("subjects")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  document.getElementById("pointsTwo").innerHTML=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("points")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
</script>
<
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

Comment: "который я выберу" – из файла на диске или по сети? Решения для этих случаев несколько разные.

Comment: надо с диска выбрать

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```js
let parse = input => {

  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function () {

    var doc = parser.parseFromString(reader.result, "application/xml");
  
    console.log(doc.body)
  }

  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

}
```

```html
<input type='file' onchange="parse(this)">
```